# Laravel test email was sent with delay

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to write a test to make sure an email was sent that has a delay on it? I am able to test that it has been pushed to the queue, but i would like to make sure that the logic in the mailer send the correct email. This is what i have, the assertPushed works, but the assertSent returns a fail.

This is how i am running the job in the controller;

```php
ProcessEmailJob::dispatch($this, $user)
    ->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```

This is the test

```php
Queue::fake();
Mail::fake();

// processing here

Queue::assertPushed(ProcessEmailJob::class, function ($job) {
    return ! is_null($job->delay);
});

Mail::assertSent(EmailUserMail::class);
```

Comment: **If your mailer is a custom one you wrote, you should test that one instead** of worrying about whether the job executed or not after the delay because Laravel framework has already done tests to confirm that the job executes with whatever is given to it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sleep(10 * 60)` inside your job handler and remove the delay from the controller code.